# Finding matching numbers in two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, oop

Hey I'm trying to write a method that compares two arrays and returns the number of values they have in common.

For example, if there are two arrays:

```
arr{0,4,2,5} 
arr1{0,7,4,4}
```

Then the method would return 2.

This is what I have so far:

```
public int numDigitsCorrect(Permutation other) {
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        for(int x=0; x<nums.length;x++) {
            if(nums[i]==other.nums[x]) {
                System.out.println(nums[i] + " " + other.nums[x] + " ");               
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: did you run the code ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: In the second loop change `x<nums.length` to `x<other.nums.length`

Comment: As of now output is 3. Add `break;` after `c++;` that will stop counting 4 twice in second array, then the output will become 2

Comment: You can introduce `Set` to improve the complexity of the code.

Comment: @Niroshan, if we invert the input then again output will be 3.

Comment: u can just find it using only one for loop if u make some logic.

Comment: He wants the output as 2 as there are only 2 Digits which are in  common for both the array

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), it will be much more cleaner and readable. Also this will reduce the complexity of your code.

Like:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class NumberMatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arrOne = { 0, 4, 2, 5 };
        int[] arrTwo = { 0, 7, 4, 4 };

        System.out.println(numDigitsCorrect(arrOne, arrTwo));
        System.out.println(numDigitsCorrect(arrTwo, arrOne));
        System.out.println(numDigitsCorrect(arrOne, arrOne));
        System.out.println(numDigitsCorrect(arrTwo, arrTwo));
    }

    public static int numDigitsCorrect(int[] arrOne, int[] arrTwo) {
        Set<Integer> setOne = arrayToSet(arrOne);
        Set<Integer> setTwo = arrayToSet(arrTwo);

        setOne.retainAll(setTwo);

        return setOne.size();
    }

    private static Set<Integer> arrayToSet(int[] array) {
        Set<Integer> retSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i : array) {
            retSet.add(i);
        }
        return retSet;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
2
4
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in current function as mention below :

```
public int numDigitsCorrect(Permutation other)  
{
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        for(int x=0; x<other.length;x++) {
           if(nums[i]==other[x]) {
               System.out.println(nums[i] + " " + other[x] + " ");               
               c++;
           }
       }
   }
   return c;
}
```

I assume that `nums` and `other` are your int arrays as shown below

```
int[] nums = {0,4,2,5}; 
int[] other = {0,7,4,4};
```